# OAuth2 authorization to 'My Anime List' not working

Tags: android, authentication, oauth-2.0, oauth

I am trying to authenticate a "My Anime List" user using Oauth2 (following this [guide](https://myanimelist.net/apiconfig/references/authorization)) for my Android application.

**Step 1:** getting the authorization token

Here, I am using a WebView to prompt the user for its username and password. This step seems to work as far as I can see.

```
private static final String REDIRECT_URL = "http://localhost/oauth";
private static final String CLIENT_ID = "9c..."; // omitted
private static final String OAUTH_BASE_URL = "https://myanimelist.net/v1/oauth2/";

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    /*
     * Before you can authenticate a user, your client needs to generate a Code Verifier and a
     * Code Challenge. A Code Verifier is a high-entropy, cryptographic, random string
     * containing only the characters [A-Z] / [a-z] / [0-9] / "-" / "." / "_" / "~".
     * The length of the string must be between 43 and 128 characters.
     *
     * MAL only allows the plain transformation for the Code Challenge.
     * In other words, it means that you have to set the Code Challenge equal to the
     * Code Verifier.
     */
    String codeChallenge = PKCEGenerator.generateVerifier(128);
    
    webview = findViewById(R.id.login_webview);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request){
            Log.d(TAG, "Redirecting to: " + request.getUrl());
            Uri url = request.getUrl();
            if(url.toString().contains(REDIRECT_URL)){
                String authorizationCode = url.getQueryParameter("code");
                Log.d(TAG, "Received authorization code: " + authorizationCode);
                webview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                getUserAccessToken(authorizationCode, codeChallenge);
            }
            return false; 
        }
    });
    authenticateMAL(codeChallenge);
}

private void authenticateMAL(String codeChallenge) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Code challenge (" + codeChallenge.length() + "): " + codeChallenge);
    String loginUrl = OAUTH_BASE_URL + "authorize" +
            "?response_type=code" +
            "&redirect_uri=" + REDIRECT_URL +
            "&client_id=" + CLIENT_ID +
            "&code_challenge=" + codeChallenge;
    Log.d(TAG, "Login url: " + loginUrl);
    webview.loadUrl(loginUrl);
}
```

As far as I can see, this works well. I am getting the `authorizationCode` as expected.

**Step 2:** Getting the user access token & refresh token

Here, I am using [Mal4J](https://github.com/Katsute/Mal4J) for the next authentication step:

```
private void getUserAccessToken(String authorizationCode, String codeChallenge) {

    Single.fromCallable(() -> {
        MyAnimeListAuthenticator authenticator = new MyAnimeListAuthenticator(
                CLIENT_ID, null, authorizationCode, codeChallenge);
        return authenticator.getAccessToken();
    })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .doOnError(throwable -> {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error while retrieving token!", throwable);
        })
        .onErrorComplete()
        .subscribe(token -> {
            Log.d(TAG, "--> access token: " + token.getToken());
            Log.d(TAG, "--> refresh token: " + token.getRefreshToken());
        });

}
```

Unfortunately, this results in the following error:

```
E/LoginActivity: Error while retrieving token!
    com.kttdevelopment.mal4j.HttpException: Server returned code 400 from 'https://myanimelist.net/v1/oauth2/token': 
        at com.kttdevelopment.mal4j.MyAnimeListAuthenticator.parseToken(MyAnimeListAuthenticator.java:505)
        at com.kttdevelopment.mal4j.MyAnimeListAuthenticator.<init>(MyAnimeListAuthenticator.java:139)
        at florian.baierl.daily_anime_news.ui.LoginActivity.lambda$getUserAccessToken$0(LoginActivity.java:99)
        at florian.baierl.daily_anime_news.ui.-$$Lambda$LoginActivity$-bBBIb9OKRzdaFNsFkQdJSeVW74.call(Unknown Source:4)
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.single.SingleFromCallable.subscribeActual(SingleFromCallable.java:43)
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Single.subscribe(Single.java:4813)
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.single.SingleSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.run(SingleSubscribeOn.java:89)
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:614)
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:65)
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:56)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Any ideas as to why that may happen? Am I missing some Android specific stuff for Oauth2? As far as I can see, I am correctly retrieving the auth code from step 1. After that, my code seems very straight-forward, so I fail to see where the error could be. Any hints are greatly appreciated!

Edit:

This is how the request looks like (from the android studio profile view):

[image]

and here is the reply:

[image]

Edit 2:

Hard coding the code challenge/verifier to 128 times 'A' (`AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA`) doesn't change the behavior either:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you include the redirect_uri in the authorization request you also need to include it in the /token request. Maybe it't that.

Comment: That's it! I removed the `redirect_uri` in the authorization request and now it works! Thanks!